# How do I print the class structures in a jar file using the javap tool?

Tags: java, command-line, javap

I want to list the methods of the class files in the jar using the javap tool. How do I do it so that it lists the methods and members of all the class files in the jar. Right now I am able to do it for just one class at a time.

I am expecting something like if I say

```
javap java.lang.*
```

it should enlist the methods and members of all the classes in java.lang package. If javap is not capable of that, are there any such tools available?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
# Set the JAR name
jar=<JAR NAME>
# Loop through the classes (everything ending in .class)
for class in $(jar -tf $jar | grep '.class'); do 
    # Replace /'s with .'s
    class=${class//\//.};
    # javap
    javap -classpath $jar ${class//.class/}; 
done
```

Comment: javap will happily disasseble class names with `/` instead of `.`, you only need to remove `.class` suffix. I am using `zipinfo -1 ${jar} \*.class| sed 's/\.class//' | xargs javap -classpath "$jar" -c -l -private > ${jar}.javap`

Answer (score 16):

Even easier would be

```
JAR=<path to jarfile> \
javap -classpath $JAR $(jar -tf $JAR | grep "class$" | sed s/\.class$//)
```

Comment: prepend JARNAME=/path/to/jar <rest of command> and that keeps the entire operation in a single line

Answer (score 2):

First unzip the jar file, this will yield a series of directories for each package, then apply the javap command per directory.

So for example with tomcat you can unzip the catalina-balancer.jar file in webapps\balancer and then use

```
javap -classpath org\apache\webapp\balancer Rule
```

which gives

```
Compiled from "Rule.java"
interface org.apache.webapp.balancer.Rule{
    public abstract boolean matches(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest);
    public abstract java.lang.String getRedirectUrl();
}
```

If you need to do this for all the class files in a package you will need to write a script or program to walk the classpath and strip the .class from the filenames and pass it to javap.

(It would be fairly easy to write in perl/bash/java).

Comment: Sure - i enjoy having extra stuff laying around my system. This works but not pretty.

Answer (score 0):

Note: You may/can also need to specify the specific jar, and the package of the class:

In general:

javap -classpath "jarpath.jarname" "package.classname"

In the above example:

javap -classpath RuleContaining.jar org.apache.webapp.balancer.Rule

Answer (score 0):

you can also specify the URL for a class in the jar to javap like this:

**javap -v jar:file:///path/to/MyJar.jar!/mypkg/MyClass.class**