# Listing the strings inside of a JAR file

Tags: java, jar, zip

I need to distribute a Java JAR file that I've written and am concerned that there may be some sensitive data that's still in the file (like passwords or keys for webapps). I've gone through the code and tried to be careful not to package anything that I don't want distributed, but I still have the fear that something slipped in.

Is there some easy way for me to dump the list of all of the constant strings that are in the class files in my JAR? I don't think the list would be TOO long and I could scan it for things that look questionable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171549/how-do-i-print-the-class-structures-in-a-jar-file-using-the-javap-tool

Comment: Are you on Linux or Windows (or something else)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Linux (or any system with Info-Zip available) you can do

```
unzip -p filename.jar|strings|sort|more
```

The `-p` option writes the extracted output to stdout, and `sort` makes it easier to scan visually.

On Windows the above works in a Cygwin terminal assuming you have the unzip package installed.

Comment: To be even "more" correct, the output should be passed through uniq, otherwise you get too much output.